# Неправильная кодировка при записи в SQLite базу через JS файл

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, nwjs

Мне нужно создать приложение на NW.JS + SQLite.

Работаю на UBUNTU. подружить SQLite3 и NW.JS получилось, но не до конца.
Для SQLite использую библиотеку [эту](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3)

```
 var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
 var db = new sqlite3.Database('app.sqlite3');

 function connect(){
     db.serialize(function() {
         db.run("CREATE TABLE qq (vopros TEXT, otvet TEXT)");

        var stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO qq VALUES (?, ?)");
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            stmt.run("Вопрос " + i, "Ответ " + i);
        }
        stmt.finalize();

        db.each("SELECT vopros, otvet FROM qq", function(err, row) {
            books.push({'vopros': row.vopros, 'otvet': row.otvet});
        });

      });

     db.close();
 }
```

После выполнения функции в базе лежат каракули. Онлайн декодер говорит, что это windows-1252. Узнавал кодировку базы через PRAGMA - UTF8. Все файлы в utf8.

Если базу заполнить руками кириллицей - всё хорошо.

Использовал библиотеку utf8 - толку не получил.

Я не могу понять в чём проблема. Прошу помощи.

Comment: У Вас сам файл-то с исходным кодом сохранен в кодировке UTF-8? А то всякое бывает.

Comment: Да, файл в  UTF8 :(

Comment: Тогда странно. На обычной ноде приведенный код отрабатывает вполне корректно. На nw.js не проверял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогла смена кодировки на UTF8 with BOM

```
¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```